# How can I read and write DICOM images in MATLAB version 7.0?

Tags: image, matlab, file-io, dicom

I am currently using MATLAB version 7.0. I need to read a DICOM image and write it back out. What functions are available to help me do this?

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use the [dicomread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/dicomread.html)/[dicomwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/dicomwrite.html) functions from the Image Processing Toolbox, but I'll recommend using one of the many functions found in the [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=dicom). Personally, I use [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29344-read-medical-data-3d).

Answer (score 1):

Look in the code at the bottom of this page
http://sites.google.com/site/dicomil/dicomandmatlab